# Angular 2 - How to map results into array

Tags: angular

I am using the below to try and convert an array with many columns into an array with 2 columns.

I can see when I do a quick watch that res contains an array called result, but i it is not mapping into the new array.

```
loadData() {
    this.selectprojectfromfavoritesService.getFavorites()
        .subscribe(res => {
            //this.TempArray.push({ label: res.result.projectNumber,   value: res.result.tzeroprojectCaptureId })
            const TempArray = res.result.map(result => { return { label: result.projectNumber, value: result.tzeroprojectCaptureId }; });
            this.values = this.TempArray ; 
        });
```

Comment: Off-site pictures really don't help. please supply the actual data directly in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You've made a mistake while getting access to `TempArray` value. It's block scoped variable (no class property) so you shouldn't use `this` keyword. Here's working example:

```
loadData() {
  this.selectprojectfromfavoritesService.getFavorites()
    .subscribe(res => {
      const TempArray = res.result.map(result => { return { label: result.projectNumber, value: result.tzeroprojectCaptureId }; });
      this.values = TempArray;
    });
}
```

BTW: it would much better (regarding data-flow management and optimization) if you'd use RxJS `map` operator to achieve this:

```
loadData() {
  this.selectprojectfromfavoritesService.getFavorites()
    .map(res => {
      return res.result.map(result => {
        return { label: result.projectNumber, value: result.tzeroprojectCaptureId };
      })
    })
    .subscribe(data => this.values = data)
}
```